# How to access value out of dictionary whose key is complex type?

Tags: c#

In writing an insurance premium calculator the basic scheme is as follows: Points are assigned to a predetermined number of attributes, such as car-value, num-incidents-in-past, years-experience-driving etc. Hene, if car worth is $3800, that lies within the 3001 to 4000 range which warrants 30 points in the premium calculation. If num-incidents-in-past is 3 or below, that warrants ZERO points. If 4-5 num-inc then points warranted is 5. If years-exp is between 1-5, that warrants 12 points. The idea is an arbitrary value is being assigned to a range of values for any given number of attributes. The premium calculations is simply tallying up the points warranted for each attribute category and multiplying by some factor i.e 2.5. I am trying to use  **B. LISKOV'S** power of abstractions AND the **SRP** to neatly assign responsiblities to design a calculator that is extensible and well designed.

Based on the answer provided by drharris here [Is there a C# type for representing an integer Range?](http://goo.gl/hAfvvJ)

How do I access the value out of the following Dictionary whose key is a generic type Range as defined by drharris?

```
 //************************ABSTRACTIONS************************
   public abstract class AbsPerson
   {
    public virtual AbsPolicy APolicy { get; set; }
    public virtual string ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address { get; set; }      
   }

public abstract class AbsPolicy
{ 
  public virtual string PersonID { get; set; } //FK
  public virtual int PropValue { get; set; }
  public virtual int InsGroup { get; set; }           
}

public abstract class AbsValueCategoryCalculator: IEvaluatePolicy
{
    //DATA
    public abstract void InitRange();
    //REFERENCE drharris poster GENERIC TYPE SIGNATURE - public class Range<T> where T : IComparable<T>
    public abstract Dictionary<Range<int>, int> ValueRange {get; set;}
    public abstract int Tally { get; set; }

    //BEHAVIOUR
    public virtual void EvaluatePolicyDetails(AbsPerson person)
    {

    }
}

public interface IEvaluatePolicy
{
    void EvaluatePolicyDetails(AbsPerson person);
}  

//*************************CONCRETIONS**************************
public class CarValueCategoryCalculator : AbsValueCategoryCalculator
{
    public CarValueCategoryCalculator()
    {//ctor
        InitRange();
    }

    public override void InitRange()
    {
        this.ValueRange = new Dictionary<Range<int>, int>();

        this.ValueRange.Add(new Range<int>() { Minimum = 1000, Maximum = 2000 }, 10);
        this.ValueRange.Add(new Range<int>() { Minimum = 2001, Maximum = 3000 }, 20);

        this.ValueRange.Add(new Range<int>() { Minimum = 3001, Maximum = 4000 }, 30);
        this.ValueRange.Add(new Range<int>() { Minimum = 4001, Maximum = 5000 }, 40);
        this.ValueRange.Add(new Range<int>() { Minimum = 5001, Maximum = 6000 }, 50);
        this.ValueRange.Add(new Range<int>() { Minimum = 6001, Maximum = 7000 }, 60);
    }

    public override Dictionary<Range<int>, int> ValueRange
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public override void EvaluatePolicyDetails(AbsPerson person)
    {
           //I am trying to tally the value given wether the cars worth lies within the range      
        if (this.ValueRange.ContainsKey(new Range<int>() { Maximum = person.APolicy.PropValue, Minimum = person.APolicy.PropValue }))
        {
            this.Tally =
        }

        Console.WriteLine("good");            
    }


    public override int Tally
    {
        get;set;
    }

}//end class
```

Comment: I think that your question and what you are actually trying to accomplish are 2 different things.  It looks like you're trying to fetch a range from a dictionary by providing a value that falls within that range.  I don't think that a Dictionary will help you here.  Can you clarify if I'm right? If so, please edit your post.

Comment: You are somewhat correct Sam. In calculating an insurance policy, points are assigned to a predetermined number of attributes, such as car-value, num-incidents-in-past, years-experience-driving etc. Hene, if car worth is $3800, that lies within the 3001 to 4000 range which warrants 30 points in the premium calculation. Proceed in like manner for the other attributes

Comment: That part of your requirement is hidden a bit too deep in your code. I don't think it was clear to anyone.  You may want to edit your post and highlight it.  Hopefully that will get you more accurate answers that can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(As noted in comments, [Sam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30648199/22656) points out that a dictionary isn't really what's wanted here - that only finds equal keys, whereas the OP is trying to find a range key that contains a single value. Hash tables just aren't geared up for that.)

You need to either override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` in `Range<T>` (which would be sensible - ideally implementing `IEquatable<Range<T>>` at the same time) or create a separate type which implements `IEqualityComparer<Range<T>>` and then pass that to the dictionary constructor.

I would probably do it on the range type, like this:

```
public sealed class Range<T> : IEquatable<Range<T>>
    where T : IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>
{
    ...

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 23;
        hash = hash * 31 + EqualityComparer.Default<T>.GetHashCode(Minimum);
        hash = hash * 31 + EqualityComparer.Default<T>.GetHashCode(Maximum);
        return hash;
    } 

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return Equals(other as Range<T>);
    }

    public bool Equals(Range<T> other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, this))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(Minimum, other.Minimum) &&
               EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(Maximum, other.Maximum); 
    }
}
```

Note that currently the `Range<T>` type is mutable, however - that's generally a bad idea for dictionary keys. It would be a good idea to make it at least "shallow-immutable" - there's not a lot you can do if the

Comment: Jon, while you may be technically correct, Sam Stanojevic. is teasing out a deeper issue, not sure who to give the answer to.

Comment: @itsjustsyntax: Up to you - my answer matches the *text* of your question, and Sam's answers what you're actually trying to achieve :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll either need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on `Range` such that the items are compared based on the values you're interested in (min and max) rather than the default behavior (which is based on the object's reference).

If you cannot mutate the type (or don't want to) then you can create a type that implements `IEqualityComparer<Range<T>>`, implements the appropriate equals and hash generation methods, and then create an instance of that comparer that you pass to the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to read between the lines here, and I think that you are asking the wrong question.

This bit of code catches my eye (you may want to make it clearer so that others understand your need better):

```
 public override void EvaluatePolicyDetails(AbsPerson person)
 {
    //I am trying to tally the value given wether the cars worth lies within the range      
    if (this.ValueRange.ContainsKey(new Range<int>() { Maximum = person.APolicy.PropValue, Minimum = person.APolicy.PropValue }))
    {
        this.Tally =
    }

    Console.WriteLine("good");            
}
```

I think that what you are actually trying to do here is fetch the associated `int` value when `person.APolicy.PropValue` is within a Range.

What you are currently doing is wrong, and will not work, even if you add the proper `Equals` and `GetHashCode` overrides.  Dictionaries only do exact matches.  You are trying to do range matching.

Instead, I suggest you drop the dictionary in favor of a List of a new type composed of a `Range` and whatever that `int` value is. Then I would sort the list based on the Range's Minimum value. Then, you could optionally do a binary search in the list to quickly find candidate `Range` objects, and then use the `Range.ContainsValue` function to verify if `person.APolicy.PropValue` is within the range.  Or, in this case, given that you only have a handful of Ranges, you can just iterate over the whole list and break out of the loop as soon as you find a Range that contains your value.

This is definitely a bit more work for you, but I think that this will get you what you are really looking for.

Comment: Sam, I gave Jon the answer check, but! I owe you much more for helping me understand what the real issue was. I did as you recommended, by adding a simple prop to the Range<T> class called PointsForRange, and it works now. Thank you so much!